# There should be a "snooze" button for items in the inbox

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

There should be a "snooze" button for items in the inbox. If I view an item, it becomes marked as read automatically, but I may want to be remindend of it again later. The snooze button would mark it as unread.

Comment: Better yet, and perhaps easier, just give us a way to mark items as “read”. Dropping down the menu and having it immediately mark all 542 notifications in my inbox as “read” is supremely annoying, and makes the feature almost useless for me. There’s no way I can read all that at one go. My browser crashes before I can open all those tabs. Much less if I just want to “peek”.